# How to access and modify state of reactjs component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

My issue is to modify a react js component attribute by an event handler.

```
export default interface WordInputProps {
    onWordChange:(word:string) => void
    firstLetter:string
    disabled?:boolean
}
```

This is my component props. I need to change the value of the boolean by clicking a button.

This is how I call my component

```
<WordInput disabled={false} key={category.id} firstLetter={currentLetter} onWordChange={(word:string) => console.log(category.name + ": ", word)} />
```

What can I do to perform the change of the boolean value from this button?

```
<button onClick={() =>
```

Comment: does the button is in WordInputComponent or in the parent?

Comment: I assume you are referring to the `disabled` prop? Where is the `disabled` prop value coming from? Where is the button in relation to the `disabled` value? The component holding the `disabled` value (presumably in state?) needs to also pass a callback function (that can be passed on to the button) to toggle this boolean value.

Comment: The button is in parent. It's why I ask how to toggle disabled statue from parent button

Comment: Yes, I'm reffering to the disabled pros. I don't know from where this value coming from. It's why I put it as a non obligatory variable. If there is a way to toogle it value from parent with a button, I am the taker of all solutions

Comment: Please include all relevant code as it seems the parent component code is important here. Once we see where this state resides, it should be a trivial matter to create a function to update *any* of *that* state's values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `state` and an update function for it:

```
// Define State
const [disabled, toggleDisabled] = React.useState(false);

// Exchange Booelan for state
<WordInput
  disabled={disabled}
  key={category.id}
  firstLetter={currentLetter}
  onWordChange={(word: string) => console.log(category.name + ": ", word)}
/>;

// Update state
<button onClick={() => toggleDisabled(prevState => !prevState)}>Toggle</button>;
```

Comment: Apart from this little detail , everything works.Thanks for your help